# How to split string by character length and not include next section of string?

Tags: python, regex

If I'm splitting a string by character length and wanted the split string to not include the next section of the string which is specified by a *comma* or by another wildcard. How do I do this whilst being below the character limit?

```py
raw_string = ('ABCD,DEFG,HIJK')
split_string = re.findall(.{1,10}, raw_string)
> split_string = 'ABCD,DEFG,H'
```

How do I set my Regex so that my string produces something like this?

```
>split_string = "ABCD,DEFG"
```

Comment: It will probably be easier to split using the `split` method of strings, rather than doing it with regex.

Comment: What if the first part is longer than 10 chars. For example: `ABCDEFGHIJKLM,DEFG,HIJK`. What would you like to return here?

Comment: @JvdV The string I'm splitting is a large one (over 800,000 characters long) so it generally doesnt matter as long as it's split before/after the comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might let it backtrack until it can assert a comma to the right.

Note that you are using `re.findall` that will return a list of matches.

```
import re

raw_string = 'ABCD,DEFG,HIJK'
split_string = re.findall(r".{1,10}(?=,)", raw_string)
print(split_string)
```

Output

```
['ABCD,DEFG']
```